# Technique to displace the top surface of a mesh only. Advice needed

Tags: materials, shaders, displacement, masking

I am trying to displace a mesh, only the top surface.[image]

You can see there is some kind of a stretch on the sides.
This is the shader node:
[image]

I would also like to use that "mask" that allows me to displace correctly just the top surface as a mask for roughness...and drive a rougher area on top too. I am specifying this cause the current setup does not allow me to isolate the roughness..I think, I am not sure.

Thank you, I can also upload the file if it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use normals of mesh. Works perfectly with cubes since you can pick one of three coords (x, y, z) and comparison mode (greater or less) to displace exactly one side of the cube. But it's more difficult with other objects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mmm that is not exactly what I am looking for. I tried with your proposal, but then I get the top surface displacing in more than one axis. I want the displaced top surface only move in Z. 
https://imgur.com/a/hSAPkW9 

Not sure how to upload images in the comment.
If you check the setup I shared in the link you will see that the displaced top surface moves only in Z , but I am trying to have the outer edges moving without stretching